# Is there a way to call CellValidating() event in DataGridView ProcessDiaglogKey()?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have overridden DataGridView ProcessDialogKey(). Here is the snippet

```
    class customDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
        protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            Keys key = (keyData & Keys.KeyCode);

            if (key == Keys.Enter)
            {
                EndEdit();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
            }
        }
```

Problem is that when I'm in celledit mode and I press enter the CellEndEdit() event fires before the CellValidating() event and my application crashes. Is there a way to call CellValidating() Event before the the EndEdit() and before CellEndEdit()?

Comment: do you have any code handling the `CellEndEdit` event? how could it be crashed if CellEndEdit is fired before?

Comment: Yes I have code handling the event. There is quantity column in which I enter integer values. The problem is that when Im in Quantity cell edit mode and I press enter lets say I type "A" and I press enter the CellEndEdit event fires and there Im calculating salesprice as Error fires invalid format value since all this checking is handled in CellValidating() event

Comment: Why don't you define your validating code in some method, you can use that method in the `CellValidating` handler and you can also use it somewhere else such as before calling the `EndEdit()`?

Comment: I i define a method and call it in cellValidating() => But the problem will remain the same as cellValidating event calls afterwards.